# Тестирования бэкэнд-приложений

Tags: юнит-тесты, тестирование, backend

Я занимаюсь бэкэндом и в основном мне приходится гонять потоки данных между разными частями клиентов. Повсюду читаю о том, как важны юнит-тесты. Я признаю их важность, когда разрабатывается какая-нибудь бизнес-логика, криптосистема или что-то другое независимое от инфраструктуры. Но как тестировать бэкэнд-приложения?

Мне нужно синхронизировать файлы между разными MongoDB, отправлять и получать документы от сервисом, делать записи в удаленных реляционках, отправлять поток данных от одного микроприложения к другому. Как для всего этого писать автотесты?

Например, файл и заголовки сохраняется в GridFS. Как это протестировать? Запрос отправляется к сервису. Как протестировать, что все нормально? Приложение открывает поток для отправки данных. Как покрыть это тестами?

Тесты для таких задач будут очень большими. Это не то же самое, что протестировать результат нелинейного преобразования в гост-шифровании.

Поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 1):

> Я признаю их важность, когда разрабатывается какая-нибудь
>   бизнес-логика, криптосистема или что-то другое независимое от
>   инфраструктуры. Но как тестировать бэкэнд-приложения?

Вы так говорите, как будто приложения с "какой-нибудь бизнес-логикой" и криптосистемы -- это приложения в вакууме. Как это они не зависят от инфраструктуры? Все приложения так или иначе зависят от инфраструктуры. Входные данные не берутся из космоса, а выходные данные не уходят в никуда.

Если приложение написано правильно, то весь код, который взаимодействует с внешним миром (будь то БД, веб-сервис или очередь сообщений), изолирован. Весь остальной код между этими точками изоляции может быть весьма легко покрыт юнит-тестами. Да, может быть так, что у вас не ахти много этой логики, особенно когда вы просто перекладываете данные из очереди сообщений в БД, например. Да, в таких случаях и юнит-тестов будет не ахти как много. Но вы хотя бы можете убедиться, не запуская само приложение, что данные корректно передаются от одной "точки изоляции" к другой внутри приложения.

Естественно юнит-тесты не гарантируют стопроцентно корректную работу приложения. Поэтому отдельная тема -- это интеграционное тестирование, когда проверяется запущенное приложение. Здесь, по возможности, опять же нужно стараться ограничить используемую инфраструктуру. Если у вас данные путешествуют по цепочке разных систем, то чтобы протестировать систему из конца цепочки, не нужно загружать данные в самую первую систему. Достаточно ограничиться "входом" и "выходом". Например, если система берет сообщения из очереди, что-то с ними делает и кладет их в другую очередь, то достаточно в интеграционных тестах создавать сообщения во входной очереди и проверять в выходной. Само собой, интеграционные тесты требуют дополнительных усилий по настройке тестовой инфраструктуры.

Ну и самый верхний уровень, это end-to-end тесты, которые проверяют всю цепочку. Особенность таких тестов в том, что их не должно быть много и что они должны проверять только happy path, т.е. нормальную работу системы. Все хитрые кейсы остаются на уровне юнит- и немного интеграционных тестов.